# Find the self-interection.Differential Geometry

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Show that the Cayley sextic
$$γ(t) = \bigl(\cos^3 (t)\cos (3t), \cos^3 (t)\sin (3t)\bigr),\quad t \in \mathbb R,$$
is a closed curve which has exactly one self-intersection. What is
its period? I can see $2π$ is its period.But for the self-intersection have to solve $γ(a)=γ(b)=p$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your curve in the form
$$\gamma: \quad t\mapsto z(t):=x(t)+iy(t)={1\over8}(e^{it}+e^{-it})^3\>e^{3it}\ .$$
Substituting $t:={u\over2}$ we obtain, after some calculation, the parametrization
$$\gamma:\quad s\mapsto{1\over8}\bigl(1+e^{iu}\bigr)^3 \qquad(u\in{\mathbb R})\ .$$
This already shows that in terms of $t$ the period is at most $\pi$. But we have to investigate in detail for which pairs $(u,v)$ with $0\leq u<v<2\pi$ the equation
$$\bigl(1+e^{iu}\bigr)^3=\bigl(1+e^{iv}\bigr)^3$$
is true. This equation is satisfied iff $1+e^{iu}$ and $1+e^{iv}$ coincide up to a third root of unity. The case $1+e^{iu}=1+e^{iv}$ is obvious. Therefore it remains to discuss the cases
$$1+e^{iu}=\omega\bigl(1+e^{iv}\bigr),\qquad1+e^{iu}=\bar\omega\bigl(1+e^{iv}\bigr)\ ,$$
where $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/3}$, or
$$\cos{u\over2}=\omega e^{i(v-u)/2}\>\cos{v\over2},\qquad \cos{u\over2}=\bar\omega e^{i(v-u)/2}\>\cos{v\over2}\ .$$
I leave this to you.

Comment: How did you obtain the first γ with the e's.

Comment: Sorry: There was a typo. I forgot the exponent $3$.

Comment: I understand you are using the de moivres formula .But Is it ok to write a parametrized curve $a(t)=(x(t),y(t))=x(t)+y(t)$ without vectors? Can you explain this part to me abit.Im just learning diff. geometry

Comment: There is an isomorphism ${\mathbb R}^2\leftrightarrow{\mathbb C}$, $(x,y)\leftrightarrow x+iy$, considered as real vector spaces. What I have done is absolutely standard when dealing with plane curves.